# Select subconsulta como expresión en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

el Siguiente Query me genera el siguiente error :

```
Mens. 512, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 46
La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.
```

el Subquery es el siguiente:

```
Select  ISNULL(s.YearlyIncome,0), s.FirstName,s.Lastname, s.BirthDate,s.MaritalStatus, s.Phone,
s.SpanishEducation,s.EnglishEducation,
DATEDIFF(Year,s.BirthDate,Getdate()) As Age,
 (Select t.BirthDate From DimCustomer t Where t.BirthDate = s.BirthDate and DATEDIFF(Year,t.BirthDate,Getdate()) <=35 ) 
   From DimCustomer s
    where s.YearlyIncome <>0 and s.YearlyIncome <=50000 and  DATEDIFF(year,s.BirthDate,GetDate())<=60 and s.MaritalStatus ='S'
```

si yo incluyo ese mismo query en un In para generar una lista todo va bien, pero al momento de tomarlo como una expresion me sale el error descrito. alguna ayuda?, utilizo sql server 2014

Comment: Cualquier subconsulta a nivel de columna solo debe devolver un valor, una única fila y una única columna. El error lo que te está diciendo es que `(Select t.BirthDate From DimCustomer ....)` está retornando más de un valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuatro maneras distintas de realizar la subconsulta.

```
 Select  ISNULL(YearlyIncome,0), FirstName,Lastname, BirthDate,MaritalStatus, Phone,
    SpanishEducation,EnglishEducation,
     DATEDIFF(Year,BirthDate,Getdate()) As Age
       From DimCustomer 
        where Birthdate in (Select Birthdate From DimCustomer Where DATEDIFF(Year,BirthDate,Getdate()) <=35) and 
        YearlyIncome <>0 and YearlyIncome <=50000 and  DATEDIFF(year,BirthDate,GetDate())<=60 and MaritalStatus ='S'


    Select  ISNULL(YearlyIncome,0), r.FirstName,r.Lastname, r.BirthDate,r.MaritalStatus, r.Phone,
    r.SpanishEducation,r.EnglishEducation,
    DATEDIFF(Year,r.BirthDate,Getdate()) As Age
      From DimCustomer r
         inner join (Select distinct BirthDate From DimCustomer Where DATEDIFF(Year,BirthDate,Getdate()) <=35) as x
           on  r.BirthDate = x.Birthdate
            Where r.YearlyIncome <>0 and r.YearlyIncome <=50000 and  DATEDIFF(year,r.BirthDate,GetDate())<=60 and r.MaritalStatus ='S'



    Select  ISNULL(YearlyIncome,0), FirstName,Lastname, r.BirthDate,MaritalStatus, Phone,
    SpanishEducation,EnglishEducation,
    DATEDIFF(Year,r.BirthDate,Getdate()) As Age
       From
        DimCustomer r ,
        (Select Distinct BirthDate From DimCustomer Where  DATEDIFF(Year,BirthDate,Getdate()) <=35 ) sq1
         where YearlyIncome <>0 and YearlyIncome <=50000 
          and  DATEDIFF(year,r.BirthDate,GetDate())<=60 and MaritalStatus ='S' and r.BirthDate=sq1.BirthDate




    Select ISNULL(y.YearlyIncome,0), y.FirstName,y.Lastname, y.BirthDate,y.MaritalStatus, y.Phone,
    y.SpanishEducation,y.EnglishEducation,
    DATEDIFF(Year,y.BirthDate,Getdate()) As Age,
    (Select distinct r.BirthDate From DimCustomer  r Where r.BirthDate=y.BirthDate   and DATEDIFF(Year, r.BirthDate,Getdate())<=60 ) sq1
       From
        DimCustomer y
         where YearlyIncome <>0 and YearlyIncome <=50000 
          and  DATEDIFF(year,y.BirthDate,GetDate())<=35 and MaritalStatus ='S'
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes conocimiento de los resultados, lo puedes solucionar añadiendo **TOP 1** a la subquery. Es peligroso hacer esto si tienes dudas ya que puedes estar camuflando un error.

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo, como se indica en [la documentación del SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017):

> «Una subconsulta introducida con un operador de comparación no
>   modificado (un operador de comparación no seguido de ANY o ALL) debe
>   devolver un valor único en lugar de una lista de valores, como las
>   subconsultas introducidas con IN. Si la subconsulta devuelve más de un
>   valor, SQL Server muestra un mensaje de error.»

De manera que si quieres obtener un solo resultado de la subconsulta tendrías que utilizar [las funciones de agregado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), como por ejemplo el MAX, entre otros. De lo contrario, tendrías que usar el IN.